# Outputting the 2-d array

Tags: c++

I am trying to output this array, and I don't know if I am being an idiot and the solution is staring at me or is there something more technical going on here.

The code:

```
 for ( string i=0;i<row; i++)
    {
        for ( string j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            out << Array[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Please note that the `Array` is a `char` datatype. `row` and `col` are defined as strings.

The errors I am getting is from Visual Studios(3 errors):

```
cpp(97): error C2676: binary '++': 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

cpp(99): error C2676: binary '++': 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

cpp(101): error C2677: binary '[': no global operator found which takes type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Please note that I tried to use ints instead of strings for the counters but I get a lot more errors...

Comment: why strings? use a number type if you want to increment it, eg `int`

Comment: Because I get a lot more errors if I change 'i' and 'j' into int.

Comment: "Please note that the Array is a char datatype. row and col are defined as strings." I'm sorry but that makes no sense and "Because I get a lot more errors if I change 'i' and 'j' into int" is actually pretty funny. Anyway, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Bane That's not a valid reason for using a `string` over an `int`. Right now, the compiler thinks your most important error is using `string` where you shouldn't be. If you fix it, it'll tell you the rest of the errors again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments. You should not fight the compiler just to remove errors or warnings, but try to understand their meaning and fix them properly. In your case, it tells you that `j++` and `i++` are illegal because the type `std::string` does not have `operator++` defined for it.

I suggest your `Array` data type have rows and columns defined as `int`, then you could write:

```
 for ( int i=0;i<row; i++)
    {
        for ( int j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            std::cout << Array[i][j];
        }
    }
```

assuming the `operator<<` is overloaded for the `Array` type, otherwise the line:

```
std::cout << Array[i][j];
```

will be illegal as well.